# conditional statement with javascript to html span

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to evaluate data inside of a HTML span tag using a javascript if statement.
how do I grab the string between the span tag and pass it to my JS code to be evaluated? Also, what is the technique of evaluating a HTML string called in JS.

example:

'''span id="tester">true</span'''

Answer (score 1):

The general situation of having plain data (of any type) inside of elements on the page, and needing to parse the data into JS, isn't uncommon, but the data format should almost always be JSON. For example, you can parse the string

```
true
```

into the boolean `true`, or the string

```
{"foo": "bar"}
```

into an object with a `foo` property.

Select the element, grab its `textContent`, and `JSON.parse` it:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector('#tester').textContent
);
console.log(data);
console.log(typeof data);
```

```html
<span id="tester">true</span>
```

Whenever transferring data this way, make sure to use JSON format if at all possible - any other format will make parsing it unnecessarily difficult.

Also, consider using a `<script>` tag (which will *not* be rendered) instead of a `<span>`, if you can:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector('[data-contains="myData"]').textContent
);
console.log(data);
console.log(typeof data);
```

```html
<script type="application/json" data-contains="myData">true</script>
```

The `type="application/json"` isn't strictly necessary, but you'll want to have *some* sort of `type` so that the browser doesn't attempt to run the data as JavaScript.